# CMake with conda-forge

Tags: cmake, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed let's say X from source by compiling.

Path location : **$HOME/Github/X_root_install**

I have also installed it via conda-forge in a conda environment.

Path location: **$HOME/anaconda3/envs/X/**

Now I have to compile a c++ file by providing installed path location.

**X_ROOT=$HOME/anaconda3/envs/X/ cmake ..**

But It found X in my **$HOME/Github/X_root_install** instead of **$HOME/anaconda3/envs/X/** location.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: That depends... how does CMake go about finding this library? Most likely there is some way to configure how CMake searches for this library

Comment: While CMake developers tend to make "standard" approaches for specify custom installations, not all projects (packages) are affected by that approaches. If you have a problem with some package, then we need to know **which exact package** you are talking about. Otherwise... we simply cannot help you.

Comment: package name : openmc

Comment: Docs: https://docs.openmc.org/en/stable/quickinstall.html

Comment: Should I change the cmakelists.txt file? [openmc](https://github.com/openmc-dev/openmc/tree/develop/examples/custom_source)